# tocloft.sty not found

Tags: miktex, tocloft

I am confused by MiKTex installation. In my LaTeX document I used `tocloft` package (with no errors) but the Package Manager said it was not installed! I wanted to make some changes in `tocloft.sty` so I installed the package, found the file and changed it a bit with no effect. Do I miss something?

BTW What I am trying to achieve is a symbol (or a word) *before* the page number. `tocloft` provides `\cftchapafterpnum` command so I thought I could define my own `\cftchapbeforepnum` command to achieve that.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You don't have an extra `tocloft.sty` lying around somewhere do you, for example in the same folder as your `.tex` file? If you look in the `.log` file you can see exactly which `tocloft.sty` is used. That said, you shouldn't really modify packages like that I think, why not add the new command to the preamble of your document?

Comment: What you want to do is easy with `titletoc` (from the `titlesec` bundle) and its `\titlecontents` command.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. The log file says `tocloft.sty` is in `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\tocloft\` while after the installation via Package Manager a new file was created in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tocloft`. It is still odd to me. And you're right, I should made changes in the preamble, not in the file itself.  
@Bernard Thanks, I will try that for sure.

Comment: Well it obviously reads the one in AppData before that in Program Files. Are the other packages loaded from AppData as well? I don't use MikTeX myself though, so I don't know why you would have that setup. Perhaps some single user versus all users installation procedure?

Comment: You have *two* package managers. The one shows the packages you did install as admin and the other one the packages installed by the user.  And don't change the files of a package!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Well, that's enlightening. I always wondered why there are two Package Managers. Thanks!

Comment: You also have two update manager. The one will update the packages in your user profile `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\ `, the other the packages of the main texmf-tree in `C:\program files`.